# Magnetic flux from an infinit wire through a Square loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics

[image]

Okay so I need to solve this exercise. I know that the magnitic field from an infinit wire is given by: $ \vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r} \hat{\phi}$, 
And that I must do an intergral looking somewhat like: $\Phi = \int_{a_1}^{a_2} \int_{b_1}^{b_2} B \cdot dA$ But what exactly do i intergrate from and to?
I guess $r$ must run from $d-a$ to $d+a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each distance $y$ from the wire, there is a segment of area of a certain width (narrow, then wider, then narrower again); this width is a function of $y$.

[image]

The magnetic field through this infinitesimal slice of area is the same everywhere since it runs parallel to the wire.

Once you realize this, you can simplify the double integral to a single integral with $y$ going from $d-a$ to $d+a$. Since the form of the width ($x$) changes with $y$ you might find it easier to write it as the sum of two integrals - one going from $d-a$ to $d$ and the other going from $d$ to $d+a$.

$$\Phi = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi}\left(\int_{d-a}^{d} \frac{(2y - (d-a))\cdot dy}{y} + \int_{d}^{d+a} \frac{(d+a-2y)\cdot dy}{y}\right)$$ 
See if that gets you going. In line with the homework policy we give hints, not complete solutions, to this kind of problem.

Comment: Well that is kind of how far I got before I asked this question.. The thing I find hard to implement is the fact that the width changes.. The width goes from $0$ to $2a$ back to $0$ ... But how do I get that into my solution without making it a double intergral? I know you can't give me the complete solution, but it's kind of the only thing there is to this exercise..

Comment: As I said - write the width as a function of $y$. This in effect is one half of the double integral, and leaves you with an integration in just $y$ (rsather than $x$ and $y$). Then write one integral to go from $d-a$ to $d$ and a second integral from $d$ to $d+a$. Two single integrals... Give it one more try, then I will write the next step out.

Comment: hmm.. I guess.. $2 \tan{(45deg)} dy = dx$.. Making $dx=2dy$. But how do I write $r$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ then ?

Comment: Okay maybe I got something.
   $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
   Taking $\frac{dr}{dy}$ I get $dr = \frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} dy$ using $x = 2y$
   gives me: $dr = - 5^{-3/2} \cdot 1/y^{2} dy$ 
   giving me the final intergral: $ \int 1/r dr = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{5y^2}} \frac{-5^{-3/2}}{y^2} dy$ This can't possibly be right...

Comment: You just write $r = y$... since the wire is infinitely long it is only the (shortest) distance from the wire to the loop that matters.

Comment: Floris can you be a little more clear?

Comment: The field is a function of $r$ - the perpendicular distance from the infinite wire. Therefore, you should not write $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ but just use $r = y$, and $B(x,y) = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi y}$. I hope that clarifies your confusion.

Comment: If I just write r = y.. then I get the the intergral:
$\int_{d-a}^{d} 1/y \cdot 2dy = 2\ln{(\frac{d}{d-a})}$ and from the upper :  $\int_{d}^{d+a} 1/y \cdot 1/2dy = 1/2\ln{(\frac{d+a}{d})}$ making $\Phi = \mu_0 / \pi \cdot (2\ln{(\frac{d}{d-a})}+ 1/2\ln{(\frac{d+a}{d})})\cdot I$ Which is not at all equal to  $ \Phi = \mu_0/\pi(a\ln{(\frac{d+a}{d-a})}+d\ln{(1-\frac{a^2}{d^2})})\cdot I$....

Comment: @Nillo - see the update to my answer. You need to write down the correct expression for the width at height $y$.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I also asked a friend of mine and he told me he had done a double intergral: intergrating over $y$ from $d-x$ to $d+x$ and then intergrating over $x$ from $0$ to $a$. With $r=y$. This gives the flux from the left/right half of the loop. Then by multiplying be two I get the full flux. But thanks a lot for your help and for not giving up on me. cheers.

Comment: @Nillo - this is one of those "borderline" questions. You were making a real effort and got stuck (in my mind) on the concept of double integration.